A fair $n$-sided die is cast $N$ times where $N \sim U\{1,\dots, n\}$. What is the modal total score?
Question:
A fair $n$-sided die is cast $N$ times where $N \sim U\{1,\dots, n\}$. What is the modal total score?

Context:
My friend asked me this question, but he doesn't have an answer to it either. The original question was "if I toss a fair $n$-sided die, take that result, then cast the die that many times, what is the most likely total score (excluding the initial cast)?".
Experimentally, the total score of $n$ seems to be the most likely outcome, but I have yet to be able to prove it mathematically.

My Attempt:
Let $X = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $N,X_1,\dots,X_n \sim U\{1,\dots,n\}$ are iid.
So the PGFs are $$G_N(t) = G_{X_i}(t) = \dfrac 1n (t+t^2+\cdots t^n) = \dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}$$
And hence $$G_{X\mid N=r}(t) = \prod_{i=1}^rG_{X_i}(t) = \bigg(\dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(t-1)}\bigg)^r$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
G_X(t) & = \Bbb E[t^X] = \displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^n\Bbb E[t^X \mid N=r] \times \Bbb P(N=r) \\
& = \sum_{r=1}^n\bigg[\bigg(\dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}\bigg)^r \times \dfrac 1n\bigg] \\
& = \dfrac{\dfrac 1n \bigg(\dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}\bigg)\bigg[1-\bigg(\dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}\bigg)^n\bigg]}{1-\bigg(\dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}\bigg)}
\end{align}
This can also be expressed as $$G_X(t) = f(f(t)) \qquad \qquad \text{where } \, \, f(t) = \dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}$$
So in principle, I have found that $$\Bbb P(X=k) = \bigg[\dfrac{1}{k!} \dfrac{\text{d}^k}{\text{d}t^k}f(f(t))\bigg]_{t=0}  \qquad \qquad \text{where } \, \, f(t) = \dfrac{t(1-t^n)}{n(1-t)}$$
However, despite how neat this looks, this is far from being an explicit expression, and analysing the modal value from this isn't easy either.
Does anyone have a different approach that might work? Thanks in advance.

Small Cases:
When $n=2$, we have:
$$G_X(t) = \dfrac 12 \bigg[\dfrac 12(t+t^2)+\dfrac 14(t+t^2)^2\bigg] = \dfrac 28 t + \dfrac 38t^2 + \dfrac 28 t^3 + \dfrac 18 t^4$$ so the modal score is indeed $2$.
When $n=3$, we have:
\begin{align}
G_X(t) & = \dfrac 13 \bigg[\dfrac 13(t+t^2+t^3)+\dfrac 19(t+t^2+t^3)^2+\dfrac{1}{27}(t+t^2+t^3)^3\bigg] \\
& = \dfrac{9}{81} t + \dfrac{12}{81}t^2+\dfrac{16}{81}t^3+\dfrac{12}{81}t^4+\dfrac{12}{81}t^5+\dfrac{10}{81}t^6+\dfrac{6}{81}t^7+\dfrac{3}{81}t^8 + \dfrac{1}{81}t^9
\end{align}
so the modal score is indeed $3$.

Analysing $P(X=k)$ for $1\leq k \leq n$:
If I cast exactly $r$ dice and require the total score to be $k$ where $1\leq r \leq k \leq n$, then this is the same as partitioning $k$ items into $r$ non-empty groups, for which there are $$C_{r-1}^{k-1} = \dfrac{(k-1)!}{(r-1)!(k-r)!}$$ ways of doing so. It follows that $$P(X=k) = \sum_{r=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n^{r+1}}C_{r-1}^{k-1} = \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{n^{r+2}}C_{r}^{k-1} = \dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} C_{r}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{n^r} = \dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{k-1}$$
for $k=1,\dots,n$. This proves that $$P(X=n)>P(X=n-1)>\cdots>P(X=1)$$
But we can't say the same for $P(X=n+1)$ etc since the maximum score on a single die is $n$.

Analysing $P(X=n+1)$:
Very similar to the previous case, except we need to disregard:

the trivial partition of having all $n+1$ items in one group
the partition of having all $n+1$ items each in their own groups

All partitions into $2$ to $n$ groups are still valid. It follows that
\begin{align}
P(X=n+1) & = \sum_{r=2}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n^{r+1}}C_{r-1}^{n} = \bigg(\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{n^{r+1}}C_{r-1}^{n}\bigg)-\dfrac{1}{n^2}- \dfrac{1}{n^{n+2}} \\
& = \dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} -\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n^n}\bigg)
\end{align}
So if we compare the expressions for $P(X=n)$ and $P(X=n+1)$, we have:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{P(X=n+1)}{P(X=n)} & = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n} -\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n^n}\bigg)}{\dfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n-1}} \\
& = \bigg(1+\dfrac 1n\bigg) - \dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{n^n}}{\bigg(1+\dfrac 1n\bigg)^{n-1}} \\
& < 1+\dfrac 1n - \dfrac 1e \bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n^n}\bigg)\bigg(1+\dfrac 1n\bigg) \\
& < 1+\dfrac 1n - \dfrac 1e \\
& < 1
\end{align}
for $n \geq 3$, since $e<3$. i.e. $P(X=n) > P(X=n+1)$, which is promising.

Well, my first step would be to work it out explicitly for small $n$.  If nothing else, that will at least give you a number of solid values that you can use to test any formula you eventually come up with.

Yeah, that's what I did actually. I've updated it with my results for $n=2$ and $n=3$, and it seems to agree with my hypothesis.

For $n=2$, the modal score is indeed $2$, but the paths to getting it seem interesting.  You can throw the sequence $(1,2)$, probability $\frac 14$, or you can throw $(2,1,1)$, probability $\frac 18$.  I would check more values.   Modal score is always a tricky thing to measure.

Also, it's easy to compute the probability that the total score is $n$.  On it's face, that maxes out the cases where the initial toss is $1$ or $2$, which seems like a good idea if you are after the mode.  Sure, you can get more paths with a higher total score if you depend on high initial tosses, but all those paths have very low probability.  Seems better to concentrate on the short paths.  Just as a hand waving argument to justify the result of $n$.

Ahhh I feel like I'm almost there with the result in my most recent update. It proves that $$P(X=n)>P(X=n-1)>P(X=n-2)> \cdots > P(X=1)$$ which feels like one half of the job done.

I'd say the only competitive contenders would be slightly greater than $n$.  If, say, you tried $n+1$ then you lose the shortest path, gain one that's just one step longer, and gain a few more longer ones.  I don't think the new paths come close to compensating for the loss of the short ones, but that should be an easy check. After you eliminate a few of those, I would think very crude estimates rule out all the others.

I finally managed to prove that $P(X=n) > P(X=n+1)$ $, ,$ :)
